# Bigquery - Query execution on UI with dataset

Tags: sql, user-interface, google-bigquery

I want to run queries from the UI without prefixing the dataset name for every table i.e. I want to set a dataset as the context first and run the query. This would help me to run the same query for different datasets without any changes. Is this possible from the UI?

Comment: there is workaround for this if you are using [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) - i will follow up with my answer and more details later when have some extra time

Comment: I dont find an option in the BigQuery mate yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it is not possible.
You can omit project id (Google use execution project in case you do not specify project in table name) - but not dataset. So in this case if you named datasets identically in different projects - you can reuse your query.
But I think it will be bad practice - using fully qualified name (project-dataset-table) gives your confidence that you are querying right data - or you can be mislead.